# How to execute functions in a for statement?

Tags: javascript

I've a two function currently, in the future I'll add much more and I want to execute it in a for statement.

Functions :

```
function load_lvl1(){

  current_lvl += 1;

  document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("level1").style.display = "block";

  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  document.getElementById("lvl").innerHTML = "Nivelul : " + current_lvl + " | Incercari : " + attemps;

}

function load_lvl2(){

  if(attemps <= 1){
  document.getElementById('error').checked = true;
  document.getElementById("lvl").innerHTML = "Nivelul : " + current_lvl + " | Incercari : " + attemps;

}
```

How to execute all functions in a for statement like this :

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
  function name[i];
}
```

Where i is id or number of the function, it need to look like :

```
function load_lvl1;
function load_lvl2;
...
```

Comment: Please give complete code. Where is current_lvl declared

Comment: current_level is a global variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an array of your functions, and then iterate that array:

```
let func = [load_lvl1, load_lvl2];
for (let f of func) {
    f(); // call it
}
```